# Assuring that $nk+k=n^3-n^2-1$ has only $4$ solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

The task is to find all pairs $(n,k)\in \mathbb{Z^2}$ for which $nk+k=n^3-n^2-1$.

In fact there are $4$ such pairs (assured by *Mathematica*): $(0,-1),~(2,1),~(-2,13)$ and $(-4,27)$.

The real question here is how to justificate that these are only solutions? Of course I could just calculate $k$ corresponding to $n$ and take $n=0,1,\ldots,20$ and then $n=-1,\ldots,-20$ but how can I be sure that there is no other answer for $n$ outside this range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the case with $n=-1$, you can write it as $k=n^2-2n+2-\frac 3{n+1}$  The last term has to be an integer, so $n+1$ divides into $3$.  There aren't too many choices.